# Disk image and recovery disk

Tags: images, hard-drive-recovery

are recovery disks (once created) the same as creating a disk image, i upgraded from vista to win 7, and had to restore my system. I had to first install the vista recovery disks and once all the updates were done I was finaly able to upgrade once again to win 7. there has to be an easier way. thanks for any help
 .

Answer (score 0):

Recovery disks (generally from the manufacturer) restore a system to a "from the factory" kind of state.

Disk images are similar, but are generally a snapshot of a system at a given point, so if you've installed other software, made configuration changes, etc, a disk image will restore the system to that state.